# How to get all values where parameter meets requirement OR does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle

I guess this should be a common use case in SQL, but I wasn't able to find anything.

I have two tables...`ITEM` and `PARAMETER` linked by `ITEM_ID` which look like this

```
====ITEM===========    ====PARAMETER===============
ID  | OTHER_COLUMNS    ID  | ITEM_ID | NAME | VALUE
===================    ============================
0                      100   0        param1  xxx   
1                      101   1        param1  yyy 
2                      102   1        param2  zzz
```

Now I want to filter items based on the parameter, but also get items which don't have the value in PARAMETER defined.

As an example, I want to select all Items with `param2=zzz`.

So the select would look like this:

```
Select * from ITEM left join PARAMETER on ITEM.id=PARAMETER.item_id 
where NAME='param2' and VALUE='zzz';
```

This will select the ITEM with ID 1, but not ITEM with ID 0, because ITEM 0 does not have set the parameter at all.

The only thing I came up with is selecting all IDs and filter out those where the parameter exists, but doesn't match.

```
select ID from ITEM where ID not in ( 
   select ID from ITEM left join PARAMETER on ITEM.id=PARAMETER.item_id 
       where NAME='param2' and VALUE <> 'zzz');
```

This works fine, but becomes messy very quickly when I want to filter by multiple parameters. Isn't there some better way to do that?

Oracle Dialect

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select *
  from item
  left join parameter
    on item.id = parameter.item_id
 where name is null
    or name not in ('param2') -- ('param2'[, 'paramN'])
    or name = 'param2' and (value = 'zzz' or value is null)
   --[or name = 'paramN' and (value = 'valueN' or value is null)]
```

**Version 2:**

Slight improvement to your query (one join excluded):

```
select id
  from item
 where id not in (select item_id
                    from parameter
                   where name = 'param2' and value <> 'zzz'
--                      or name = 'paramN' and value <> 'valueN'
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work because all non-matching parameters will be in the output. For case of 'param1' and 'xxx' the desired output would only be ITEM 0, because ITEM 1 has 'param1' set but with wrong value. But when I use your select, it also returns ITEM 1 because of different parameter - 'param2'.

Comment: Version 2: Thanks, I missed that :D